# Excel - search function with wildcards

Tags: excel, search, boolean

I have the following formula:

```
=(OR(ISERR(SEARCH("20??",F3871,1))=FALSE,F3871="",F3871 = "Customer Number:"))
```

which is setup as a helper column in order to pull another formula and manipulate some data.

My issue is that some of the products we have are being counted in the first OR section (ex. code 1320-T is being counted because there are 2 values to the right of 20 ), however the goal was to only select the years beyond 2005 only.

Is there a way to change the first parameter of SEARCH to reflect only years starting with 20.

Perhaps there is a better formula to use

Thank you.

sample data:

```
FALSE   1142-CR
FALSE   1142-TL
FALSE   1320
TRUE    1320-T
```

Note: There is a mix of years and products in this column which is why I am trying to clean it up and put the data into a table. Most products this will not be an issue but a few have the "20" in them

Comment: Can you give us a clearer idea of your data set? Is the year included in the code usually (e.g. 132005-T) or is it similar to 2005-T?

Comment: Do you mean you only want a match when the cell value starts with "20"? If so you could try using LEFT function, e.g. LEFT(F3871,2)="20"

Comment: @barryhoudini that's a good point I could try that. It looks like this works, I knew I was over-complicating it!. Thanks!